# Matrix diagonalizable or not

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ is in $M_3(\mathbb R^3)$ which is not a diagonal matrix. Pick out the cases when $A $ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb R$:

a. when $A^2=A$;

b. when $(A-3I)^2=0$;

c. when $A^2+I=0$.

My attempt is if $A$ is diagonalizable then there is some invertible $P$ s.t. $PAP^{-1}$=$D$.

Then case a. gives $D^2$=$D$. then $D$ is either $0$ or $I$. Which gives $A$=$0$ or $I$..a contradiction to the fact $A$ is not diagonal. But I am not sure about my approach. Similarly I arrive contradiction for other cases. Please help.

Comment: you are saying that all three are wrong?

Comment: I am not sure. I am asking...and shared my thinking...

Comment: I am not saying you are correct or wrong.. just confirming what you meant

Comment: yes@ Praphulla Koushik

Comment: fine fine...  what characterizations you know concerned with diagonalizability if you know something about minimal polynomial...

Comment: I dont know about what you are saying.

Comment: A matrix is diagonalizable if its minimal polynomial has no repeated roots.... you heard about this?

Comment: S according to you we can rule out case b. But what about the others? I am also asking you " matrix is diagonalizable if its minimal polynomial has no repeated roots" how?

Comment: That is a standard result.. you can get in any standard linear algebra book...

Comment: ok. what about case a and c?

Comment: for that also you need same result... you practically need nothing more than that!

Comment: OK I would type whole answer at once and leave some gaps in between you please try to fill that out...

Answer (score 2):

Result :

A matrix is diagonalizable if its minimal polynomial has no repeated roots.

For first case $A^2=A$ minimal polynomial could be :

- $x$ What does this mean if $x$ is minimal polynomial for $A$.. does something goes wrong?
- $x-1$ What does this mean if $x$ is minimal polynomial for $A$.. does something goes wrong?
- and the other possibility is ???

You should be able to complete that i believe.

For second case $(A-3I)^2=0$ what could be the minimal polynomials?

For third case $A^2+I=0$ minimal polynomial would be $???$

That polynomial do not have roots in $\mathbb{R}$ so there is no question of diagonalizability over $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would dispose of these issues:

For (c.), note that a matrix $A \in M_3(R)$ has at least one real eigenvalue, since its characteristic polynomial is of degree 3, and real polynomials of odd degree have at least one real root.  But if $A^2 + I = 0$, the eigenvalues $\lambda$ of $A$ must satisfy $\lambda^2 + 1 = 0$, i.e. $\lambda = \pm i$.  This shows there is no matrix $A \in M_3(R)$ satisfying $A^2 + I = 0$.  Thus the proposition,

"$A \in M_3(R) \; \text{and} \; A^2 + I = 0 \Rightarrow A \; \text{is diagonalizable over} \; R.$"

is vacuously true.

For (b.), let

$A = \begin{bmatrix} 3 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 3 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 3 \end{bmatrix}; \tag{1}$

then

$(A - 3I)^2 = N^2 = 0, \tag{2}$

where

$N = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}. \tag{3}$

We now see that $A$ cannot be diagonalizable over $R$; for, since the only eigenvalue of $A$ is $3$ by virtue of $(A - 3I)^2 = 0$, if there were a nonsingular real matrix $P$ with
$PAP^{-1}$ diagonal, we would have

$PAP^{-1} = 3I; \tag{4}$

but (4) implies $A = P^{-1}(3I)P = 3I$, contradicting (1).  This example can be generalized in the following sense:  any non-diagonal $A$ satisfying $(A - 3I)^2 = 0$ may clearly be written as $A = 3I + N$, with $N \ne 0$ satisfying $N^2 = 0$.  The only eigenvalue of such $A$ is $3$; thus $PAP^{-1}$ diagonal forces $A = 3I$, exactly as we have just seen.  This contradicts $N \ne 0$.

Finally, for (a.), use the Jordan form: if $A$ were *not* diagonalizable, each Jordan block J would have to satisfy $J^2 = J$; but $J = \lambda I + N$ with $N = [n_{ij}]$, and $n_{ij}  = 1$ iff $j = i+ 1$, $n_{ij} = 0$ otherwise; so $J^2 = \lambda^2 I + 2\lambda N + N^2 \ne J$; thus $A$ can be diagonalized.

Hope this helps.  Cheers,

and as always, ***Fiat Lux!!!***

Finally, as for

Comment: @ Git Gud:  having checked the link you provided, I put to you the question:  how do your matrices satisfy $A^2 + I = 0$?  I continue to ponder this as I await your response.  Thanks and Regards.

Comment: My apologies. I don't know what I was thinking (maybe thinking about $A^2=I$?). I deleted my previous comment.

Comment: @Git Gud:  No need to apologize, sometimes the heat of mathematics overpowers the light for al of us!  By the way, is the "Git" in "Git Gud" related to the "git" of "github"?  Regards.

Comment: Nop, it's [1337](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leet) for "get good" ^_^